# Zend nested navigation is not working with ACL

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation, zend-acl

I am unable to get nested Zend_Navigation to work with Zend_ACL. I used XML to define my navigation. Please refer to it here: http://pastebin.com/GA8uQdKh

The problem is that the nested elements such as **filelabel** do not show up on the web page.
I can make them appear by removing the **resource** element or by turning off the ACL.
Here is the filelabel element just by itself: http://pastebin.com/E7vTYcBy

What am I doing wrong?  Please feel free to ask any question if something in my question does not make sense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a `<resource>` and `<privilege>` tag to each menu item